# How to remove open actions and javascript from pdf

Tags: security, pdf, virus-scanning

Is there a way to quickly remove `open actions` and `javascript` from `pdf`s (without damaging/affecting the contents)?

I download `pdf`s regularly and often see messages like this:

[image]

when scanning the `pdf` with [virustotal](https://www.virustotal.com/#/home/upload). What would be great is if there is a way to quickly remove `open actions` and `javascript` from the `pdf` (from say, a CLI command, online interface, or python script) (or at least see the code that the `pdf` intends to run, have tried using a text editor to look for `/JS` or `/JavaScript` text in `pdf`s but the content seems like something garbled that I can't interpret).

Currently, using Mac Preview, I `export as pdf` to get rid of some of these things, but it does not always work. Have also tried [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/103323) solution, but often can't open the `.postscript` that it generates.

I understand that Mac Preview does not support javascript, but I often would like to transfer these files to other people on other OSs and these `open actions` and `javascript` makes me nervous for their computers.

Don't know much about computer security or pdf structures, so any suggestions and advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: that should be easy to implement using any proper general purpose pdf library.

Comment: In most cases, you *will* be damaging the PDF by removing the open actions. The file will *look* the same but it won't *function* as the author intended. The most common open actions are ones inserted by Acrobat automatically when a file has been distributed for review or data collection. The script runs and checks that the correct viewer version and variation is being used and throws a dialog when the file won't work properly in the environment it's been opened in. In other cases, a licenseing dialog will open when the PDF is first opened. You don't want to remove that either.